# Auto Typing Function Issue on Live Server: Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT: So my auto typing function working on Codepen: https://codepen.io/ScottFSchmidt/pen/dzNmNr 
 ...but just not my live server with the exact same code:
https://scottschmidtportfolio.000webhostapp.com/

```
I will post my scripts since that is the first place to probably look.
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<title>SS Studio</title>
<meta charset = "UTF-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/fab417e5fd.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>

<script language="javascript">
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(document).scrollTop() > 50) {
    $('nav').addClass('shrink');
  } else {
    $('nav').removeClass('shrink');
  }
}); //end scroll func
```

Comment: it has no problem on my phone. Nexus 5, chrome.

Comment: yes working fine on my mobile too

Comment: Ok I will double check...I should probably add a lengthy background..so I can do a scroll down test and see it it "pops" up

Comment: Ok so it is working on codepen on phone... Let me try adding back into my live server portfolio and see if it works. Last time it was on a live server a few months ago I had to take it out and never got back to this issue until now...

Comment: https://scottschmidtportfolio.000webhostapp.com/
It doesnt work on a live server I bet my scripts are wrong somewhere or overwriting each other...might just make a new topic's issue has changed now.

Answer (score 0):

Adding these two scripts seemed to work:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```